# How to update ini file in java using classpath

Tags: java, ini, ini4j

I have one question in java `.ini` files writing.

I am using `ini4j`. How to update `.ini` file using class path or relative path or resource stream?

I am not able to update ini files using classpath.

If I give entire path then it is working, I dont want to give entire path. I just want to give file name and want to update the file.

```
Wini ini1 = new Wini(new File("C://resources//sf-dv1.ini"));
```

Comment: 'Classpath paths' are really for resources, and resources are read-only. You should pass the path you want as a parameter. As long as it's valid, Java won't care whether it's relative or absolute